# installing postgres 9.2 on Mac OSX 10.6 with KyngChaos package

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, postgis, postgresql-9.2

I'm trying to install `postgres 9.2` on a mac 10.6 using using KyngChaos (because ultimately I'd like to enable `PostGIS`, and this seems to be the best package to that with).

I get exactly the problem spelled out at the bottom of the page: http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/postgres

--

NOTE: I've had reports of the installer not initializing the data cluster, which results in Postgres not starting. It seems to be random, and I haven't figured out the cause yet. If Postgres won't start (you get an error "could not connect to server: No such file or directory" when trying to connect with psql), try manually initializing the cluster with:

```
/usr/local/pgsql-9.1/bin/initdb -U postgres \
-D /usr/local/pgsql-9.1/data --encoding=UTF8 --locale=en_US"
```

Or see the Locales and Encodings readme if you need a different locale or encoding.

Then stop and start Postgres as specified in the readme.

--

I run

```
/usr/local/pgsql-9.1/bin/initdb -U postgres -D /usr/local/pgsql-9.1/data --encoding=UTF8 --locale=en_US"
```

which opens up a new line to enter additional commands with 
>
but i'm lost there, even after combing the readme.

Comment: The last problem is due to a missing quote. It should be `--locale="en_US"` (but not sure if this is the only problem).

Comment: wow yes. thank you. that command runs now but I still get the same error when typing psql

Comment: Did you run `export PATH=/usr/local/pgsql-9.2/bin:$PATH` ? You say you are installing `9.2` but the commands you are running afterwards are for `9.1`.